# Iterate through ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, contains

I'm currently trying to `iterate` through an `ArrayList` and see if it contains the following numbers I input into the winners array. However, the ticket `object` won't allow me to utilize the `.contains()` method which is where I'm getting the error. Any idea on how to work around this?

```
int[] winners = new int[6];
for(int i = 0; i < winners.length; i++)
    {
        winners[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    in.close();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<Ticket> info = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
    {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String num = scan.nextLine();

        String[] t = num.split(" ");
        int[] tichold = new int[t.length];

        for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++)
        {
            tichold[j] = Integer.parseInt(t[j]);
        }

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(name, tichold);
        info.add(ticket);
    }

    **for(Ticket t : info)
    {
        if(t.contains(winners))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
    }**

    scan.close();
}

**public static class Ticket
{
    public String name;
    public int[] tarray;

    public Ticket(String name, int[] tarray)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.tarray = tarray;
    }**
```

Comment: What is *the* error?

Comment: Does yout `Ticket` class contain, `contains()` method?

Comment: And what is the `Ticket` class?

Comment: No ticket class does not have a contain method

Comment: `Ticket` class is placed in the very end of code in question

Comment: Also, we don't know anything about `winners` as an object.

Comment: So, Beginner, now know what produces the error?

Comment: `winners` is array of integers (first for loop linitializes it)

Comment: If it doesn't contain that method. Why are you trying to use it then?

Comment: Don't you want to see if `winners` contains the ticket's number?

Comment: Please update the question with the definition of winners and the error or exception that you receive in java.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I'm trying to simulate a lottery game and see if the numbers entered into the winners[] is in the Ticket t object after I iterate through the array list

Comment: I'm thinking you want to check the `winners` array to see if it contains the `Ticket`

Comment: hmm, if i buy a ticket on a lottery i have to check if my ticket contains winning numbers.

Comment: His logic is fine, he just didn't implement contains method

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a method that doesn't exist for that class.  Since you don't have `contains` defined for `Ticket`, I'm not surprised that it isn't working.

From inference, `winners` is an `int[]`.  In that case, you'd define a new method `contains` inside of `Ticket`.

```
public boolean contains(int[] winningNumbers) {
    // logic here
}
```

Depending on how the winning numbers for a given ticket are stored, and given how you define different conditions of winning, you'd handle your logic here.

If they're stored as an array and you want an exact match, then you can use [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-) for that.

```
public boolean contains(int[] winningNumbers) {
    return Arrays.equals(numbers, winningNumbers);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is where I was confused on for the most part

Answer (score -1):

Try this Ticket class with and added contains method:

```
public class Ticket {
    public String name;
    public int[] tarray;

    public Ticket(String name, int[] tarray)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.tarray = tarray;
    }

    public boolean contains(int[] winners) {
        for (int i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tarray.length; j++) {
                if (winners[i] == tarray[j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```